# JDBC connection not recognizing an existing Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created a database named 'test' from my browser, and now trying to access it from java code using JDBC driver and syntax as:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "pw");
            st = con.createStatement();
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test'
```

I searched for it and I get possible solution as "Create the DB named 'test'", but that already exists there. What could be the reason and how to deal with it?

**EDIT:**

My conf file has a snippet like:

```
# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

which shows that the port is indeed 3306

Comment: check whether the database is created or not using terminal.

Comment: I checked it using the browser and it is there.

Comment: Does the user you use to connect actually have access rights to the database `test`? (I know you connect with `root`, but it never hurts to check).

Comment: in browser also, i am logging with username : "root" and password "pw". Otherwise how to check that?

Answer (score -2):

You seem to have forgotten your port number. The default is 3306. So you could change it to

`con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "pw");` and see if this works.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that and edited question, that doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to specify the default port. The driver will assume the default if no port is explicitly specified